# example xml configuration of spring oauth 2

Tags: java, xml, spring, oauth, spring-security

I'm trying to implement add an oauth2 security scheme to my project,
the oauth2 authentication server is already implemented by another project so all I need is to intercept relevant requests and use the the auth server in order to login,
additionally, I want to use the auth server as an authorization provider by using the users' groups has roles in the application,
my current spring security xml looks like this:

```
<security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/loginError.html" security="none" />
    <security:http use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.html"
                                access="permitAll"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.html"
                             authentication-failure-url="/loginError.html"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login.html"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="user" password="p" authorities="VIEW"/>
                <security:user name="admin" password="p" authorities="ALL, VIEW"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

    <oauth:resource-server id="oauthResourceServer" entry-point-ref="entry"/>
    <bean id="entry" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <constructor-arg value="https://www.example.com" />
    </bean>
```

also, we're using a `web.xml` with this filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
```

The current authentication-manager is going to get moved to a development profile, and of course is not expected to be used alongside the oauth server.
I'm aware that it's probably best to move to spring 4 and have configuration in code like the examples but it is not possible for me at this time so the current configuration mechanism should be maintained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this example in an older version of the current github repository:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/114fbd44beef0382009f207c08f0b1d9c24e95a9/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml

there are more examples in here:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/tree/master/samples

under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF in each of the projects

Answer (score 2):

i have a working project of oAuth 2.0, with all 3 component, you can find it [in GitHub](https://github.com/OhadR/oAuth2-sample) with explanations. I support there spring 3, spring 4 and spring 5, all configured with XML.

for example, for spring-5, the authorization-server is configured this way:

```
<security:http pattern="/login/**" security="none" />


<!-- Protect the /oauth/token url to allow only registered clients -->
<!-- this statement enables the access to /oauth/token. without it we get "cannot access" -->
<security:http pattern="/oauth/token"  
    use-expressions="false"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="ROLE_CLIENT"/>
    <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:http-basic />

    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>

</security:http>


<security:http auto-config="true" 
    use-expressions="false"
    authentication-manager-ref="usersAuthManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/publicKey" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

    <security:form-login 
        login-page="/login/login.htm" 
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-url="/login/login.htm?login_error=1" />


    <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>

    <!-- >security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" /-->
    <!-- security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" /-->

</security:http>



<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="usersAuthManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <security:user name="user@ohadr.com" password="uripass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <security:user name="demo@ohadr.com" password="demo" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</security:user-service>


<!-- OAuth2 Configuration -->
<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" 
    token-services-ref="myAuthorizationServerTokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="automaticUserApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<security:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client client-id="${com.ohadr.oauth2.client.name}"
        secret="${com.ohadr.oauth2.client.secret}" 
        scope="read,write,trust"
        authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,refresh_token" 
        authorities="ROLE_CLIENT"/>
</oauth:client-details-service>


<bean id="passwordEncoder"  class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="256"/>
</bean>
```

...

Comment: After I use your config, my authentication manager got mess up with user authentication manager, and client authentication manager.

Comment: Did you try to have a look at the github link in the answer?

Comment: I managed it to work now by change `<security:authentication-manager alias"..">` to `<security:authentication-manager id"..">`. Anyway, thank you. Your example help a lot. :)

Comment: One more question, what should I have implement more after I got redirect back with this url `http://localhost/resources/login?code=2ZNIV7&state=qNSqLA3QDagJl4fZovBZjNF2oNe0Ri-KaQ2EjiOIGAk%3D`

Comment: What do u mean "have to implement"? The redirect back is the call to the resource server with the token...